# How to initialize global variable for an embedded device?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing code using Qt under Linux (Ubuntu) for an embedded device.
I arranged a header file with global variables declaration inside; when I tested my project under Linux on my PC, everything is OK. When I try my project with the embedded system, sometimes it doesn't work, because I forgot to initialize some variables (seems that on my PC, Qt automatically set to "0" their values, while on the embedded they can have a random value).

Is there a way to initialize in one step all my variables, in such a way that when I pass them to my embedded the global variables are already correctly initialized?

Comment: Global variables getting initialized is a C++ feature, not a Qt feature. From what you posted it looks like your embedded compiler produces incorrect code. Try updating or file a bug report.

Comment: What compiler are you using? as nwp suggests, I believe, for c++, all static storage variables (like globals) should be zero initialised by default.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some code ?
When using global variables, you need to define them in a C/C++ file and initialize them here. The declaration in the header only says "Hey ! this one exists ! " even if not...

Comment: namespace Ui {
        class ts400;

    }

class ts400 : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ts400(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ts400();
    quint8 MonoCutModeIndex;       
    quint8 MonoCutModeIndexTemp;    // all these global variables must be initialized; if not, I found them with random value in embedded.

Comment: This code is in your header (including global variables ) ? Did you put the global variables definition in a cpp file ? By the way, in C/C++ you should not assume that variable are automatically initialized.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanna do is to be sure that every global variable I create in my header file is initialized with "0" value. Is there a method, a pragma, an additional C++ header to do this?